# error whiile adding fire base into ng app

Tags: firebase, angularfire, ng

i am installing firebase into my ng app but encountering this issue when i add in imports array as shown in the documentation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yRyq.png)
Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
Type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Provider[] | undefined'.
Type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
Type 'Provider | EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.

Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
Types of property 'providers' are incompatible.
Type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Provider[] | undefined'.
Type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'.
Type 'Provider | EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.